# Convert exist Vue UI library units to px

Tags: css, node.js, vue.js, webpack

I was wondering about how can I convert the **whole existing units** (em / rem) to **pixels**?

Right now I am using [Vuesax](https://vuesax.com) UI to make a plugin for any websites/templates (overlap)

But they are using units like rem or em.

How can I convert **the whole output units to px** easy (any trick)?

For example, I would like to put some config/plugin in **vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {},
  css: {},
  chainWebpack: config => {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I believe that not to be possible, `rem` and `em` get converted to `px` in real time by the browser, but they are dynamic values, they are different from pixels and you cannot set them statically during compilation.

Remember that `rem`s (as a result also `em`s can) can depend on the user declarations set in the browsers, meaning that if a website uses `rem`s it will adapt to the font-size set by the user in the browser and that is absolutely something that you cannot predict or enforce.

I have seen some websites setting a pixel font-size in the root element so that what you can know `rem`s and `em`s values in any case, but that is a bad practice, plus you said you wanted your plugin to work on any website/template, so I do not think that would be a viable solution for you.

Moreover ignoring the browser's font-size issue, personally I believe that `em`s would be very difficult (or impossible) to compute statically as they, when used for font-sizes depend on the parent element and otherwise on the element itself, the latter doesn't look to much of a problem but the former definitely is.

All in all I think that what you're trying to achieve is not feasible, since fundamentally `rem`s, `em`s and `px`s are different concepts and can only be converted at compilation time to pixels by the css parsing system.